# ReferenceError: “require” is not defined - AngularJs ngHint

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm tying to make ngHint work.

I have followed this blogpost http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/11/06/exploring-angular-1.3-angular-hint.html

After running "npm install angular-hint" like they do in this article, I got under node_modules the angular-hint folder with no dist folder.

I have added the node_modules/angular-hint/hint.js to my index.html.

But I get in Chrome console the following error:

> hint.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Any ideas?

Comment: require.js library is missing, check path